# How to copy records to a table, but not if they are already there

Tags: mysql, copy, duplicates

I have 3 tables I use as a filing mechanism for training documents, a document table (a30), a training manual table, which stores the titles and ids of the different training manuals (a36trnman), and a table to store the id's of the documents that are associated with the different manuals (a31).

In my application, I allow a user to copy a training manual, along with its associated documents and make it their own.  However, I run into a problem because different training manuals may include the same documents, and then there would be duplicates of that document now in their training manual(which they may have modified, and will want to be preserved). So, I need a duplicate training manual query that checks to see if a document in the manual being copied already exists for that user, and if it does, to leave it in place, and create a new record in the table `a31` that associates the existing (old) document with the training manual that has just been added.

My documents

```
CREATE TABLE `a30` (
  `docname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `docfile` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `docfilepdf` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `ctgry` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `subctgry` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `id` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `creator` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `smmry` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='haha!! training materials!' AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;


CREATE TABLE `a31` (
  `pntryid` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pdocid` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `trnmannum` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pntryid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='document pantry' AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;


CREATE TABLE `a36trnman` (
  `unik` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `ctgryname` char(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`unik`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=88 ;
```

My current query which 1. copies the training manual, 2. stores the training manual id, 3. then copies the list of associated document id's into the table a31, 4. copies the documents into the table a30. How do I have the query check for existing duplicates in a30 and leave them be, but still add an entry to a31 with reference to the new training manual?

```
SET @userid =  <code type="user" />;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `a1t` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `a36trnman` WHERE `unik` =  '<input     name="unik" hidden="y" />';
  UPDATE a1t SET `unik` = NULL;
  INSERT INTO `a36trnman` (SELECT * FROM `a1t`);
  DROP TABLE `a1t`;
SET @lastid := LAST_INSERT_ID();

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `a1t` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `a31` WHERE `trnmannum` =  '<input     name="unik" hidden="y" />';
  UPDATE a1t SET `pntryid` = NULL, `trnmannum` = @lastid;
  INSERT INTO `a31` (SELECT * FROM `a1t`);
  DROP TABLE `a1t`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `a30t` ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT docname, docfile, docfilepdf, ctgry, subctgry, id, creator, smmry FROM `a30` LEFT JOIN `a31` ON a30.id = a31.pdocid WHERE `trnmannum` = @lastid;
  UPDATE a30t SET `id` = null, `creator` = @userid;
  INSERT INTO `a30` (SELECT * FROM `a30t`);
  DROP TABLE `a30t`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can with your current schema

Ideal way would be to add another column to the documents table and populate it with a uniqueid.
Then change you document links table to use that instead of the auto inc id.

Then you could insert just those documents that weren't already in there based on the new identifier, as it would never change, where as your auto increment id must.

The links table would just work as you'd be using the new  immutable key.

So baically documents would have two unique identifiers, one auto inc and one that was mysql's equivalent of guid.

Comment: in my documents table there is a unique id, its the `a30.id` column.

Comment: If it's unique, why are you setting it to null and regenerating when you copy? I'm saying you need an identifier that is unique across all "copies". You are geting duplicates Because a document "FredBlogg" has an id of 1 in one place and 2 in another. It's duplicated but it's id isn't.

Comment: gotcha.  i'll play around with that!